# Using the second row of a delimited text file as the header row when importing into Access 2010.

Tags: import, ms-access-2010, csv

Is it possible to use the values of the second row of a delimited text file (e.g. a csv file) as the header row when importing into Access 2010?

Comment: Hi - why is the second row the header row? What's in the first? Can the first row be deleted?

Comment: Actually, I have to manually delete first row and then import the file so 2nd row automatically becomes row header.I don't want to use specification while importing because i have a bulk of text files to be imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the headers have to be in the first line of the imported file. You need to delete the empty first line of data.

If there are too many files for this to be practical, as you imply, you have a couple of options.

1. Presuming the headers are the same on all of your files to be imported, you could combine all of the text files into one file and import that.
2. If the headers are different, you could write some code to batch delete the first line from all your files, as is suggested [here](http://www.accessforums.net/import-export-data/csv-import-second-row-contains-column-headings-15149.html).